# Japanese characters Encoding Issues

Tags: c#, winforms, character-encoding, textbox, ocr

I am using a third party OCR Library  to convert an Image containing Japanese characters to a text file. The Text file created looks alright when I open it by double clicking but when I load it in TextBox using the code below it becomes strange.

```
   this.textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(Outpath);
```

Comment: i think you need to use `RichTextBox` control.

Comment: Well what's the encoding of the text file?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Rich TextBox didnt seem to work

Comment: @JonSkeet I dont actually know the format, where can I adjust the format of the Text input?

Comment: @electricalbah: That's not what you need to adjust. You need to specify the encoding in the `File.ReadAllText` call, unless it's UTF-8. You *must* find out the text encoding of the file. It should be documented by your OCR library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReadAllText method can take the encoding as a parameter.

for a japanese file you should probably use:

```
this.textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(Outpath, Encoding.Unicode);
```

if your file is encoded in UTF8:

```
this.textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(Outpath, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Hope this helps,

Sylvain

Comment: Ok I will accept your answer as it helped me solve the problem and maybe useful to others. What actually solved my own problem was this.richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(Outpath, Encoding.Default);

Comment: Thanks. Now that you mention it, I used Encoding.Default too. But my OS is in japanese. May I ask if you were using japanese OS ?

Comment: Yes my OS is Japanese.

Comment: Ok, this is why it worked for us, as I could find on MSDN : Encoding.Default "Gets an encoding for the operating system's current ANSI code page.". On an English OS it would probably not work and I think you would have to use one of the encoding I mentioned (Unicode or UTF8).